# why composer ignore my php version

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a silex project where my server have PHP 5.3.3, update PHP is not on the table.

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.3.3"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "1.2.*",
        "twig/twig": ">=1.8.0,<2.0-dev",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.3,<2.7",
        "twig/extensions": "1.2.*@dev",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.4,>=1.4.1",
        "vrana/notorm": "dev-master",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "dev-master",
        "symfony/security": "2.6.*"
    }
}
```

My problem is that symfony/security install version 2.6.13 and in dependencies there is this line
symfony/http-kernel: ~2.4

that install symfony/http-kernel 2.6.16
and symfony/http-kernel 2.6.16 have like requirement symfony/debug: ~2.6,>=2.6.2
but instead install symfony/debug: 2.6.16 composer install symfony/debug: 2.8.15 and that version require PHP 5.3.9

here is the error

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/debug v2.8.15 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[v2.8.15].
    - symfony/debug v2.8.15 requires php >=5.3.9 -> your PHP version (5.3.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/debug v2.8.15 requires php >=5.3.9 -> your PHP version (5.3.3) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/http-kernel v2.6.13 requires symfony/debug ~2.6,>=2.6.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[v2.8.15].
    - Installation request for symfony/http-kernel v2.6.13 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v2.6.13].
```

How can I fix that?

Guys, the problem is this line

```
- symfony/http-kernel v2.6.13 requires symfony/debug ~2.6,>=2.6.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug[v2.8.15].
```

look the debug version that want and the version that get

Comment: You'll probably ignore this, but I **_strongly_** urge you to reconsider this statement: "update PHP is not on the table". PHP 5.3.3 was released on **_July 22, 2010_**, a whopping six and a half years ago. PHP 5.3 has not received any security updates since _August 14, 2014_, almost two and a half years ago, with the release of PHP 5.3.29. Refusing to update is, frankly, irresponsible.

Comment: sorry but it's not my call, if were for mi we should have PHP 7.1 or at least PHP 5.6 but the server is shared, and update PHP is not on the table

Comment: @Emiliano Is getting your site hacked on the table?

Comment: which is the proposal?

Comment: @Emiliano You are running a dangerously insecure unsupported version of PHP. Either updating PHP is on the table, or being hacked is. I suggest that updating PHP is the more responsible choice, even if it means getting onto a new host.

Comment: I understand that this version is old, I got it, really I got it. but the real world is not ideal and sometimes you need do something that is not the best but is need it.

Comment: @Emiliano The real world has preventable and non-preventable disasters. This is one of the preventable ones. If your shared host hasn't updated PHP in nearly seven years, *what else are they behind on?*

Comment: I don't want discuss about the things that should be that not are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it deleting the file called composer.lock and executing

```
composer clearcache
composer update
```